# Code signing hell! - Application failed codesigning verification

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing

While trying to upload to the app store I have come along all sorts of problems with code signing, I have tried to fix by deleting all certificates and profiles and trying again but nothing seems to work, I have tried deleting everything again so it is easier for you to help.

Here is what I now have:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image]

Comment: Before saying it is a duplicate, I have read through many similar questions with no luck :(

Comment: It seems like you're trying to code sign with provisioning profile instead of with distribution one.

Comment: Downloaded a distribution certificate which shows 'Valid signing identity not found' in the organiser window.

Comment: Kind of :) try following RyanG's guidelines - it should work.

Comment: If your certificate is not Valid-- it is because it is not fully/correctly installed in Keychain Access, and it most likely means you do not have the private key associated with that distribution cert. Did you just create the dist cert or was it already created?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue and get your app submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning you are getting says it all.

You are trying to submit your app using a Development provisioning profile-- you need to create a Distribution profile and use that to submit. Development certificates can only be used for development (obviously) and ad-hoc builds.

Check this Apple doc out to see how to create one.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html

Once you do that, make sure you switch your Code Signing Identities to that Distribution profile and try to submit again.

It should go through fine if you have it all setup correctly.

Comment: Link is dead. Either update that or copy the bullet points to your answer, please.